# Mathematica: Changing the options of a Graphics object

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to change the options of a Graphics object? Say you are working with a graphics object `G2D` as in the following picture

[image: Sample]

You can see from the `InputForm` of `G2D` that the `PlotRange` option is set to `{{-0.025,1.025},{0,1.05}}`. But later on on the code I decided to change the `PlotRange` option to a different one. What happens with the `InputForm`? The new option simply gets appended.

You can obtain the options set by a graphics object by using `Options` and `AbsoluteOptions` but I haven't found a way to change those options. The function [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html) seemed like a likely candidate but it turns out that
this function only works with streams and functions. That is, it only allows to set the default behavior as they show in the examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to clean up the set of options in the graphic, it's probably easiest to just construct the graphic anew.  You can extract the main body of the graphic with `First`, and use `DeleteDuplicates` and `Options` to get the simplified list of options:

```
old = Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}];
old = Show[old, ImageSize -> 1000];
old = Show[old, ImageSize -> 500];
old = Show[old, ImageSize -> 250];
old = Show[old, ImageSize -> 100]

InputForm[old]

new = Graphics[First[old], 
  DeleteDuplicates[Options[old], First[#] === First[#2] &]]

InputForm[new]
```

I've used `Options` because the options to `Graphics` can be, but aren't always, enclosed in a list, and `Options` will standardize the form.

I'd also like to point out that technically `Show` is prepending the option values, so the duplicated options aren't really harming anything, although they can make it harder to debug graphics output and slightly increase the size of the file.

[image]

---

You can also use SetOptions to change the default value for *all* graphics:

```
SetOptions[Graphics, Background -> Gray];

Graphics[Disk[]]
```

[image]

Comment: Brett, I don't know if you noticed but I used Show in my original post, at least in the picture. The problem I have is that the new options you are defining are simply being appended to a list. If you notice in my picture the option PlotRange is being included 3 times in the last time I use InputForm. All I want is a clean definition that says what the PlotRange is.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The text in the image was small so I didn't actually read it closely.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused, did you edit your answer a second time or are you about to edit it once more? In any case, I posted a link to SetOptions which is something that does not solve the problem. I need to make sure that when you use InputForm you only see one instance of an option.

Comment: I just made the third edit.  :-)  The second was to show how `SetOptions` can be used in conjunction with `Graphics`.  (Although I don't generally suggest doing so.)

Comment: Thanks Brett. This works just the way I wanted it, now I can keep everything clean. Just one more thing, could you explain a little about how to make the test expression to check that you are deleting the duplicates?

Comment: The function takes two arguments (represented here by # and #2), which will each be an option.  Options are rules, and have a `FullForm` of `Rule[name, value]`, so I'm using `First` to extract the name.  Then I compare them with `===` (aka `SameQ`.)